# In objective-c, efficient way to write a uint8_t array to a binary file?

Tags: objective-c

I have a large one dimensional `uint8_t` array and I can not figure out an efficient way to send it to a binary file without first converting it to NSData.  Is there a more efficient way to get my array into a file than converting it first?

Thanks,
Dale

EDIT: Test code for answer (in viewDidLoad), THIS ALSO READS FROM A FILE DIRECTLY TO uint8_t ARRAY:

```
  filemgr= [NSFileManager defaultManager];
  dirPaths= NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
  dataDir= dirPaths[0];
  NSLog(@"Data dir is %@",dataDir);
  dataPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/junk.bin",dataDir];
  report_memory();
  [self read_file];
  report_memory();
  [filemgr removeItemAtPath: dataPath error: Nil]; //TODO remove after test
  if (![filemgr fileExistsAtPath:dataPath]){
     memset(ONOFFrecords,0xFF,8388608); //set all bytes of ONOFFrecords to 0xFF
     [[NSData data] writeToFile:dataPath atomically:YES]; //make empty file
    report_memory();
     double strt= CACurrentMediaTime();
     NSData* ONOFFdata = [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:&ONOFFrecords[0] length:sizeof(ONOFFrecords) freeWhenDone:NO];
     NSFileHandle *handle= [NSFileHandle fileHandleForWritingAtPath:dataPath];
     [handle seekToFileOffset:0];
     [handle writeData:ONOFFdata];
     [handle closeFile];
     NSLog(@"8 MB file of uint8_t's created and saved in %f secs to all 0xFF's", CACurrentMediaTime()-strt);
     report_memory();
  } else {
    report_memory();
    //lets read that file and put it in uint8_t ONOFFrecords
    [self read_file];
     report_memory();
  }
  //TODO remove below after test
  //lets read that file and put it in uint8_t ONOFFrecords
  report_memory();
  [self read_file];
  report_memory();
  //lets change some of that data
  ONOFFrecords[0] = 0x03;
  //and save write all data to the same file
  report_memory();
  double strt= CACurrentMediaTime();
  NSData *ONOFFdata = [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:&ONOFFrecords[0] length:sizeof(ONOFFrecords) freeWhenDone:NO];
  NSFileHandle *handle= [NSFileHandle fileHandleForWritingAtPath:dataPath];
  [handle seekToFileOffset:0];
  [handle writeData:ONOFFdata];
  [handle closeFile];
  NSLog(@"Updated 8 MB file of uint8_t's WRITE in %f secs with first uint8_t = %u", CACurrentMediaTime()-strt,ONOFFrecords[0]);
  report_memory();
  //lets read that file and put it in uint8_t ONOFFrecords
  report_memory();
  [self read_file];
  report_memory();
```

AND the read_file function:

```
- (void) read_file
{
  NSInteger result;
  uint8_t buffer[4096];
  uint32_t pos = 0;
  uint8_t haderr = 0;
  double strt= CACurrentMediaTime();
  NSInputStream *iStream = [[NSInputStream alloc] initWithFileAtPath:dataPath];
  [iStream open];
  while ((result = [iStream read:buffer maxLength:4096]) != 0){
     if (result>0){
        memcpy(ONOFFrecords+pos, buffer, result);
        pos+=result;
     }else{
        haderr=1;
        NSLog(@"Error %@",[iStream streamError]);
        break;
     }
  }
  [iStream close];
  if (haderr==0){
     NSLog(@"8 MB file of uint8_t's READ in %f secs with first uint8_t = %u last pos %u", CACurrentMediaTime()-strt,ONOFFrecords[0],pos);
  }
}
```

AND the report_memory() function (needs the #import too):

```
#import <mach/mach.h>
```

//...

```
void report_memory(void)
{
  struct mach_task_basic_info info;
  mach_msg_type_number_t size = MACH_TASK_BASIC_INFO_COUNT;
  kern_return_t kerr = task_info(mach_task_self(),
                                            MACH_TASK_BASIC_INFO,
                                            (task_info_t)&info,
                                            &size);
  if( kerr == KERN_SUCCESS ) {
     NSLog(@"Memory in use (in bytes): %llu", info.resident_size);
  } else {
     NSLog(@"Error with task_info(): %s", mach_error_string(kerr));
  }
}
```

AND the output:

```
2017-02-23 12:17:41.530929 HaloLog[2107:1026526] Data dir is /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/C448DBF6-5FF8-4272-BA57-6595D07AB6E5/Documents
2017-02-23 12:17:41.531127 HaloLog[2107:1026526] Memory in use (in bytes): 29302784
2017-02-23 12:17:41.532333 HaloLog[2107:1026526] Error Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory" UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=2, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1}
2017-02-23 12:17:41.532425 HaloLog[2107:1026526] Memory in use (in bytes): 29306880
2017-02-23 12:17:41.583930 HaloLog[2107:1026526] Memory in use (in bytes): 29392896
2017-02-23 12:17:41.604554 HaloLog[2107:1026526] 8 MB file of uint8_t's created and saved in 0.020386 secs to all 0xFF's
2017-02-23 12:17:41.604748 HaloLog[2107:1026526] Memory in use (in bytes): 29392896
2017-02-23 12:17:41.604899 HaloLog[2107:1026526] Memory in use (in bytes): 29392896
2017-02-23 12:17:41.635276 HaloLog[2107:1026526] 8 MB file of uint8_t's READ in 0.030260 secs with first uint8_t = 255 last pos 8388608
2017-02-23 12:17:41.635422 HaloLog[2107:1026526] Memory in use (in bytes): 29392896
2017-02-23 12:17:41.635460 HaloLog[2107:1026526] Memory in use (in bytes): 29392896
2017-02-23 12:17:41.652201 HaloLog[2107:1026526] Updated 8 MB file of uint8_t's WRITE in 0.016660 secs with first uint8_t = 3
2017-02-23 12:17:41.652303 HaloLog[2107:1026526] Memory in use (in bytes): 29392896
2017-02-23 12:17:41.652342 HaloLog[2107:1026526] Memory in use (in bytes): 29392896
2017-02-23 12:17:41.678894 HaloLog[2107:1026526] 8 MB file of uint8_t's READ in 0.026464 secs with first uint8_t = 3 last pos 8388608
2017-02-23 12:17:41.679007 HaloLog[2107:1026526] Memory in use (in bytes): 29392896
(lldb)
```

Comment: why dont you just use C to handle that?

Comment: Because I am still a newbie and doing the conversion was all I could figure out.  But it really seems inefficient to me to do that because it is 8 MB long.

Comment: Do you mean you want to write the uints as just integers (literally a text file with numbers in it)?

Comment: No I want it to be a binary file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use NSData's [`dataWithBytesNoCopy:length:freeWhenDone:`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsdata/1547240-datawithbytesnocopy?language=objc). You'll get back an `NSData` object which references your data, but without it making a copy of it. Make sure to pass `NO` for `freeWhenDone`, otherwise, the `NSData` object will attempt to free the bytes you've passed in when it's deallocated, which you probably do not want.

```
uint8_t myArray[] = {
    0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05
};

NSData* theData = [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:&myArray[0]
                                       length:sizeof(myArray)
                                 freeWhenDone:NO];
```

Then use whatever method to write the `NSData`, perhaps `NSFileManager` or an `NSFileHandle`.

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I asked for.  Could you please comment on my test code which I have added to my original post?  Am I using it correctly?  Will I have memory issues if I change my array data and save regularly as I did in my test code?

Comment: Also, is there a way to do this in 'reverse', I mean, read data from a file and put it directly into my uint8_t array?