# In objective-c, efficient way to READ data from a binary file directly into a uint8_t array?

Tags: objective-c, arrays

I have a large one dimensional uint8_t array and I can not figure out an efficient way to populate it with data from a binary file without first importing the data as NSData. Is there a more efficient way to get my uint8_t array populated without importing as NSData first?

I have asked this question in a roundabout way in my other answered post concerning ([WRITE uint8_t array directly to binary file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42401767/in-objective-c-efficient-way-to-write-a-uint8-t-array-to-a-binary-file)) but I am not sure the answer is the same. You can see my attempt at coding a read there.

Thanks, Dale

EDIT:  Sorry, actually I wanted synchronous/blocking but I found out how to do that with NSInputStream, so I made a rough test code function to do it.  The code runs and leaves memory usage the same at the end (less about 4096 which ARC should take care of) as when it started so I think I am happy now :) unless someone sees a problem with my implementation??

Test code for answer:

```
- (void) read_file
{
  NSInteger thisRead;
  uint8_t inbuffer[4096];
  uint32_t pos = 0;
  uint8_t haderr = 0;
  double strt= CACurrentMediaTime();
  NSInputStream *iStream = [[NSInputStream alloc] initWithFileAtPath:dataPath];
  [iStream open];
  while ((thisRead = [iStream read:inbuffer maxLength:4096]) != 0){
     if (thisRead>0){
        memcpy(ONOFFrecords+pos, inbuffer, thisRead);
        pos+=thisRead;
     }else{
        haderr=1;
        NSLog(@"Error %@",[iStream streamError]);
        break;
     }
  }
  [iStream close];
  if (haderr==0){
     NSLog(@"8 MB file of uint8_t's READ in %f secs with first uint8_t = %u last pos %u", CACurrentMediaTime()-strt,ONOFFrecords[0],pos);
  }
}
```

Comment: Is that asynchronous?

Comment: You can create an [input stream from a file](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsinputstream/1564839-inputstreamwithfileatpath?language=objc), set up a [delegate](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsstream/1418423-delegate?language=objc) to handle [read events](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsstreamdelegate/1410079-stream?language=objc), then [schedule it on a runloop](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsstream/1417370-scheduleinrunloop?language=objc) in a background thread (if you need it to run in the background).

Comment: Whichever thread you're on, make sure to schedule it in the [currentRunLoop](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsrunloop/1412291-currentrunloop?language=objc). When there are bytes available to be read, you can copy them out of [the input stream's buffer](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsinputstream/1416811-getbuffer?language=objc) into your `uint8_t` array.

Comment: If this handles what you're looking for, I can put this in an answer.

Comment: Thanks all, NSInputStream rocks!

Comment: Why only 4096? 64k might be more reasonable

Comment: When I researched this I saw this and since it came from Apple....'The best approach is to use some reasonable buffer size, such as 512 bytes, one kilobyte (as in the example above), or a page size (four kilobytes).'.... in https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Streams/Articles/ReadingInputStreams.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002273-BCIJHAGD

Comment: "unless someone sees a problem with my implementation?" - probably not a good idea to test `thisRead > 0` but then *always* copy 4096 bytes...

Comment: Thanks, I thought it was just like a Boolean flag but it looks like it tells me how many bytes were read, up to 4096.  I guess maxLength should have been a clue or better research.